# Moongoose update slug

Tags: node.js, npm

I am using the package mongoose slug generator
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-slug-generator
But my slug is not updated when the category is updated
My Model

```
const {Schema, model} = require('mongoose')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const slug = require('mongoose-slug-generator')

mongoose.plugin(slug)
const categorySchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  slug: {
    type: String,
    slug: "title"
  },
})
categorySchema.set('timestamps', true)

module.exports = model('categories', categorySchema)
```

My controller

```
module.exports.update = async (req, res) => {
  const $set = {title: req.body.title}
  try {
    const category = await Category.updateMany({_id: req.params.id}, {$set}, {new: true})
    res.json(category)

  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json(e)
  }
}
```

If I specify a slug in the set, then it will be saved in the language in which the title will come